# req.query is not working in Http.createserver in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, httpserver

Hai Everyone I'm beginner in NodeJS I could not get the value whatever given the data in the get request.It shows the error **"Cannot read property 'user' of undefined"**.This is the url which I given in the browser is 
http://localhost:8086/dopath?user=viki&pass=vino
I attached the code.can anyone solve this issue?Thanks in advance...

```html
"use strict";
let http=require('http');
let url=require("url");
let port=process.env.PORT||8086;
function handler(req,res)
{
    if(req.url!="/favicon.ico")
    {
        let urldata=url.parse(req.url);
        console.log(urldata);
        console.log("Request Method:"+req.method);
        console.log("Request URL:"+req.url);
        console.log("Username:"+req.query.user);
        console.log("Password:"+req.query.pass);
        res.statusCode=200;
        res.setHeader('content-Type','text/plain');
        res.end("I 'm sending data username is "+`${req.query.user}`+"and password is "+`${req.query.pass}`);
    }
}
let server=http.createServer(handler);
server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server is listening on port",`${port}`);
});
```

Comment: `req.query` exists in expressjs. `http` module does not pass parsed request object as an argument. so You've to parse `req.url` and detect query part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use spaces in your code, hard to read otherwise. Also use `const` instead of `let` when variable won't change. You forgot to use the parsed urlData.

Try this:

```
'use strict'

const http = require('http')
const url = require('url')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8086

function handler (req, res) {  
  if (req.url !== '/favicon.ico') {
    const urlData = url.parse(req.url, true)

    console.log(req.query)
    console.log(urlData)
    console.log('Request Method:' + req.method)
    console.log('Request URL:' + req.url)
    console.log('Username:' + urlData.query.user)
    console.log('Password:' + urlData.query.pass)
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.end("I 'm sending data username is " + `${urlData.query.user}` + 'and password is ' + `${urlData.query.pass}`)
  }
}

const server = http.createServer(handler)

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('server is listening on port', `${port}`)
})
```

Comment: well, I am running it with http://localhost:8086/dopath?user=foo&pass=bar and seems fine. How do you run your server?

Comment: Thanks now It's working fine.I have missed the true parameter in url parse.

Comment: Your welcome. Please, don't forget to accept the answer.